# Sum named vector values where the names are reversed in R

Tags: r

I have a list of named vectors. I am trying to sum their values. But some of the names within a vector have reversed equivalents. For example, if I have some data that looks like this:

```
myList <- list(`1` = c('x1:x2' = 2, 'x2:x1' = 1, 'x3:x4' = 1),
               `2` = c('x1:x2' = 3, 'x6:x1' = 2, 'x1:x1' = 1, 'x4:x3' = 1),
               `3` = c('x3:x4' = 2, 'x1:x2' = 1, 'x4:x3' = 4),
               `4` = c('x5:x2' = 1, 'x2:x5' = 1)
               )
> myList
$`1`
x1:x2 x2:x1 x3:x4
    2     1     1

$`2`
x1:x2 x6:x1 x1:x1 x4:x3
    3     2     1     1

$`3`
x3:x4 x1:x2 x4:x3
    2     1     4

$`4`
x5:x2 x2:x5
    1     1
```

Here, we can see that in `myList[[1]]` we have `x1:x2 = 2` and `x2:x1 = 1`. As these are the reverse of each other, they are equivalent, so, essentially, `x1:x2 = 3`.

I am trying to sum the values for each named element (including the reverse) over each list element.

My desired output would look something like this:

```
    var count listNo
1 x1:x2     3      1
2 x3:x4     1      1
3 x1:x2     3      2
4 x6:x1     2      2
5 x1:x1     1      2
6 x4:x3     1      2
7 x3:x4     6      3
8 x1:x2     1      3
9 x5:x2     2      4
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is tricky. I'd be interested to see a more elegant solution

```r
`row.names<-`(do.call(rbind, Map(function(vec, name) {  
    x <- names(vec)
    l <- sapply(strsplit(x, ":"), function(y) {
      paste0("x", sort(as.numeric(sub("\\D", "", y))), collapse = ":")
      })
    df <- setNames(as.data.frame(table(rep(l, vec))), c("var", "count"))
    df$listNo <- name
    df
  }, vec = myList, name = names(myList))), NULL)

#>     var count listNo
#> 1 x1:x2     3      1
#> 2 x3:x4     1      1
#> 3 x1:x1     1      2
#> 4 x1:x2     3      2
#> 5 x1:x6     2      2
#> 6 x3:x4     1      2
#> 7 x1:x2     1      3
#> 8 x3:x4     6      3
#> 9 x2:x5     2      4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: If all of the names are of the form 'x', single digit, ':', 'x', single digit then it seems to me that once you split on ':', you can just do string sorting. With multiple digits, you have the issue of whether 'x10' gets sorted as earlier than 'x2', so you'd want to 0-pad all your numbers (or just accept that things have a lexigraphical order).

Answer (score 10):

### Solution

Here is a base R approach mixed with `dplyr::bind_rows()`:

```
tmp <- lapply(1:length(myList), function(i) {
  tapply(setNames(myList[[i]], 
                  sapply(strsplit(names(myList[[i]]), ":"), 
                         function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = ":"))), 
         sapply(strsplit(names(myList[[i]]), ":"), 
                function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = ":")), sum)
})

bind_rows(tmp, .id = "listNo") |> 
  pivot_longer(!listNo, names_to = "var", values_to = "count", values_drop_na = T)

# A tibble: 9 x 3
  listNo var   count
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
1 1      x1:x2     3
2 1      x3:x4     1
3 2      x1:x2     3
4 2      x3:x4     1
5 2      x1:x1     1
6 2      x1:x6     2
7 3      x1:x2     1
8 3      x3:x4     6
9 4      x2:x5     2
```

### microbenchmark

Out of curiosity, I've run `microbenchmark` on existing answers, and it seems like @ThomasIsCoding's solution has beaten @AllanCameron to be the best in terms of time:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Allan = {
    `row.names<-`(do.call(rbind, Map(function(vec, name) {  
      x <- names(vec)
      l <- sapply(strsplit(x, ":"), function(y) {
        paste0("x", sort(as.numeric(sub("\\D", "", y))), collapse = ":")
      })
      df <- setNames(as.data.frame(table(rep(l, vec))), c("var", "count"))
      df$listNo <- name
      df
    }, vec = myList, name = names(myList))), NULL)
    },
  benson23 = {
    tmp <- lapply(1:length(myList), function(i) {
      tapply(setNames(myList[[i]], 
                      sapply(strsplit(names(myList[[i]]), ":"), 
                             function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = ":"))), 
             sapply(strsplit(names(myList[[i]]), ":"), 
                    function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = ":")), sum)
    })
    
    bind_rows(tmp, .id = "listNo") |> 
      pivot_longer(!listNo, names_to = "var", values_to = "count", values_drop_na = T)
    
  },
  tmfmnk = {
    map_dfr(myList, enframe, .id = "listNo") %>%
      mutate(var = map_chr(str_split(name, ":"), ~ str_c(sort(.), collapse = ":"))) %>%
      group_by(listNo, var) %>%
      summarise(count = sum(value))
  },
  zephryl = {
    tibble(count = myList, listNo = names(myList)) %>%
      unnest_longer(count, indices_to = "var") %>% 
      mutate(
        var = str_extract_all(var, "\\d+"),
        var = map_chr(var, ~ str_glue("x{sort(.x)[[1]]}:x{sort(.x)[[2]]}"))
      ) %>% 
      group_by(listNo, var) %>%
      summarize(count = sum(count), .groups = "drop")
  },
  PaulS = {
    map_dfr(myList, identity, .id = "listNo") %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = -listNo, values_drop_na = T) %>% 
      rowwise %>%
      mutate(name = str_split(name, ":", simplify = T) %>% sort %>% 
               str_c(collapse = ":")) %>% 
      group_by(name, listNo) %>% 
      summarise(count = sum(value), .groups = "drop") 
  },
  TIC1 = {
    aggregate(
      count ~ .,
      transform(
        cbind(
          setNames(do.call(rbind, Map(stack, myList)), c("count", "var")),
          listNo = rep(seq_along(myList), lengths(myList))
        ),
        var = sapply(
          strsplit(as.character(var), ":"),
          function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = ":")
        )
      ),
      sum
    )
  },
  TIC2 = {
    aggregate(
      count ~ .,
      cbind(
        var = unlist(sapply(
          myList,
          function(x) {
            sapply(
              strsplit(names(x), ":"),
              function(v) paste0(sort(v), collapse = ":")
            )
          }
        )),
        setNames(stack(myList), c("count", "listNo"))
      ),
      sum
    )
  },
  Maël = {
    myList %>% 
      imap(~ .x %>% 
             enframe() %>% 
             separate(name, into = c("c1", "c2")) %>% 
             graph.data.frame(., directed = F) %>% 
             get.data.frame() %>% 
             group_by(from, to) %>% 
             summarise(count = sum(value)) %>% 
             unite(c("from","to"), col = "var", sep = ":") %>% 
             mutate(listNo = .y)) %>%
      bind_rows()
  })

Unit: milliseconds
     expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
    Allan  2.1327  2.25920  2.475978  2.33445  2.45270  12.3697   100 a   
 benson23  3.5083  3.80855  4.150929  4.03700  4.27685  13.3313   100 a   
   tmfmnk  5.4928  5.88520  6.324940  6.24190  6.66975   8.1777   100 ab  
  zephryl 10.1629 10.89110 14.813878 11.58475 12.14085 221.0931   100   c 
    PaulS  7.7565  8.44360 11.402325  9.10860  9.47480 124.1965   100  bc 
     TIC1  3.5233  3.88805  8.240207  4.06640  4.26765 202.9082   100 a c 
     TIC2  1.8722  2.03240  2.247993  2.13230  2.24045  10.7320   100 a   
     Maël 35.3066 39.52920 44.456091 40.96870 42.39480 170.8322   100    d
```

Answer (score 9):

Another `tidyverse` option could be:

```
map_dfr(myList, enframe, .id = "listNo") %>%
    mutate(var = map_chr(str_split(name, ":"), ~ str_c(sort(.), collapse = ":"))) %>%
    group_by(listNo, var) %>%
    summarise(count = sum(value))

  listNo var   count
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
1 1      x1:x2     3
2 1      x3:x4     1
3 2      x1:x1     1
4 2      x1:x2     3
5 2      x1:x6     2
6 2      x3:x4     1
7 3      x1:x2     1
8 3      x3:x4     6
9 4      x2:x5     2
```

Answer (score 8):

Another possible solution, `tidyverse`-based:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map_dfr(myList, identity, .id = "listNo") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -listNo, values_drop_na = T) %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(name = str_split(name, ":", simplify = T) %>% sort %>% 
         str_c(collapse = ":")) %>% 
  group_by(name, listNo) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(value), .groups = "drop") 

#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>   name  listNo count
#>   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 x1:x1 2          1
#> 2 x1:x2 1          3
#> 3 x1:x2 2          3
#> 4 x1:x2 3          1
#> 5 x1:x6 2          2
#> 6 x2:x5 4          2
#> 7 x3:x4 1          1
#> 8 x3:x4 2          1
#> 9 x3:x4 3          6
```

Answer (score 8):

A {tidyverse} solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
               
tibble(count = myList, listNo = names(myList)) %>%
  unnest_longer(count, indices_to = "var") %>% 
  mutate(
    var = str_extract_all(var, "\\d+"),
    var = map_chr(var, ~ str_glue("x{sort(.x)[[1]]}:x{sort(.x)[[2]]}"))
  ) %>% 
  group_by(listNo, var) %>%
  summarize(count = sum(count), .groups = "drop")

# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   listNo var   count
#   <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
# 1 1      x1:x2     3
# 2 1      x3:x4     1
# 3 2      x1:x1     1
# 4 2      x1:x2     3
# 5 2      x1:x6     2
# 6 2      x3:x4     1
# 7 3      x1:x2     1
# 8 3      x3:x4     6
# 9 4      x2:x5     2
```

Answer (score 4):

Two base R options using `aggregate` + `stack` + `strsplit`

```
TIC1 <- function() {
  aggregate(
    count ~ .,
    transform(
      cbind(
        setNames(do.call(rbind, Map(stack, myList)), c("count", "var")),
        listNo = rep(seq_along(myList), lengths(myList))
      ),
      var = sapply(
        strsplit(as.character(var), ":"),
        function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = ":")
      )
    ),
    sum
  )
}
```

or

```
TIC2 <- function() {
  aggregate(
    count ~ .,
    cbind(
      var = unlist(sapply(
        myList,
        function(x) {
          sapply(
            strsplit(names(x), ":"),
            function(v) paste0(sort(v), collapse = ":")
          )
        }
      )),
      setNames(stack(myList), c("count", "listNo"))
    ),
    sum
  )
}
```

give

```
> TIC1()
    var listNo count
1 x1:x2      1     3
2 x3:x4      1     1
3 x1:x1      2     1
4 x1:x2      2     3
5 x1:x6      2     2
6 x3:x4      2     1
7 x1:x2      3     1
8 x3:x4      3     6
9 x2:x5      4     2

> TIC2()
    var listNo count
1 x1:x2      1     3
2 x3:x4      1     1
3 x1:x1      2     1
4 x1:x2      2     3
5 x1:x6      2     2
6 x3:x4      2     1
7 x1:x2      3     1
8 x3:x4      3     6
9 x2:x5      4     2
```

---

## **Benchmark**

```
microbenchmark(
  TIC1(),
  TIC2(),
  Allan()
)
```

shows

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
  TIC1() 4.2614 4.43265 4.902491 4.68145 4.89585 13.2152   100
  TIC2() 2.2116 2.29665 2.707671 2.51175 2.63690 10.3980   100
 Allan() 2.4817 2.59040 3.006702 2.71535 2.91005 16.6410   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here is a `data.table` solution. Would be interesting to see how well the different approaches scale with larger lists.

```r
library(data.table)
rowSort <- \(a) matrix(a[order(row(a), a)], nrow=dim(a)[1], byrow=TRUE, dimnames=dimnames(a))
res <- rbindlist(lapply(myList, \(count) as.data.table(count, keep.rownames="var")), idcol="listNo")
res[, c("p1", "p2"):= tstrsplit(var, ":")]
res[, var:=apply(rowSort(as.matrix(res[,.(p1,p2)])), 1, paste, collapse=":")][,
    .(count=sum(count)), .(listNo, var)]
#>    listNo   var count
#> 1:      1 x1:x2     3
#> 2:      1 x3:x4     1
#> 3:      2 x1:x2     3
#> 4:      2 x1:x6     2
#> 5:      2 x1:x1     1
#> 6:      2 x3:x4     1
#> 7:      3 x3:x4     6
#> 8:      3 x1:x2     1
#> 9:      4 x2:x5     2
```

For the provided (small) example list, this modification seems to be slightly faster (and narrowly beats the others on my machine):

```r
tsrt <- \(x) vapply(strsplit(x, ":"), \(y) paste0(sort(y), collapse=":"), FUN.VALUE = NA_character_)
    res <- rbindlist(lapply(myList, \(count) as.data.table(count, keep.rownames="var")), idcol="listNo")
    res[, var:= tsrt(var)][, .(count=sum(count)), .(listNo, var)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `igraph` library, you can create an undirected graph and sum the values. Even though a bit longer, this solution uses functions that I think are easier to understand.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

myList %>% 
  imap(~ .x %>% 
        enframe() %>% 
        separate(name, into = c("c1", "c2")) %>% 
        graph.data.frame(., directed = F) %>% 
        get.data.frame() %>% 
        group_by(from, to) %>% 
        summarise(count = sum(value)) %>% 
        unite(c("from","to"), col = "var", sep = ":") %>% 
        mutate(listNo = .y)) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  var   count listNo
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
1 x1:x2     3 1     
2 x3:x4     1 1     
3 x1:x1     1 2     
4 x1:x2     3 2     
5 x1:x6     2 2     
6 x4:x3     1 2     
7 x1:x2     1 3     
8 x3:x4     6 3     
9 x5:x2     2 4
```